# Discontinuous records, missing time gaps.

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have a table `Item_X` which has primary columns as `Item_id,Country,Date_from`.
Other column not part of `PK` are `Date_To`, `TypeOfSale`.
There are there `TypeOfSale` as 1, 2, 3.

For a particular period of time only on type of sale is valid.
For Ex:-
[image]

Date From is always Date_to + 1.

I have some records in my table which are discontinuous.
Example:-
[image]

Record from 1st Feb to 29th Feb is missing.

**I want to find out all such records.**
First record should not be considered and last record can have To_date as null.

Comment: Do you have a column which determines an _order_ of these sales records?

Comment: @AJ- Are the intervals supposed to be calendar months, or is that just a coincidence in your sample input? If there are three consecutive months missing, do you need three rows in the output, or just one (showing, for example, 1 Oct 2015 and 31 Dec 2015)? Also, what are the beginning and the end date OVERALL? Or do you only need the gaps BETWEEN existing rows, and not also before the first row or after the last? Are the date columns in character data type, or actual date datatype?

Comment: Or... wait...  are you asking to show the existing rows in your table, where there are gaps? What exactly do you need the output to look like?

Comment: They need to be dates, if three consecutive months missing then i need the next/previous record, if some dates are missing, then also next/previous record. First record should not be considered and last record can have null in To_Date, that should also not be considere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select r.*
from records r
where not exists (select 1 from records r2 where r2.item_id = r.item_id and r2.date_from = r.date_to + 1) and
      exists (select 1 from records r2 where r2.item_id = r.item_id and r2.date_from > r.date_to);
```

This returns the first record before the gap.

Another method uses `lead()` and `lag()`:

```
select r.*
from (select r.*,
             lead(date_from) over (partition by item_id order by date_from) as next_date_from,
             lag(date_to) over (partition by item_id order by date_from) as prev_date_to
      from records r
     ) r
where (date_from <> prev_date_to + 1) or
      (date_to <> next_date_from - 1);
```

This returns both records.

Comment: There should also be a check for country, first record should not be considered and last record can have null in To_date